# How to convert a python list to another data type in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Write a function that creates a numpy array with the float64 type based on an existing list

```
import numpy as np

def solution(lst):
    arr = #your code here
    return arr
```

I try a lot of ways:

import numpy as np

```
def solution(lst): 
   arr = np.array(lst) 
   arr = lst.astype(np.float64) 
return arr

import numpy as np 
def solution(lst): 
   arr = np.array(lst) 
   arr = np.astype(np.float64) 
return arr
```

Comment: are you trying to create a numpy array that only contains floats from a list?

Comment: @rachelyw yes..

Comment: `astype` is a method of an array, not a method of a list, and not a function of `np`.  The error messages should have told you that.  Have you spent much time reading the basic `numpy` docs?

Comment: `np.array(lst, dtype=np.float64)` or `np.array(lst).astype(np.float64)`.  When documentation like https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html#numpy.ndarray.astype give a signature like `ndarray.astype(...)` that means it's a `method` of an array, not a `numpy` function.  The distinction between function and method is important when working with Python (at all levels).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good question will have a minimal test case, and show the errors that you get with various tries.

Define a small list:

```
In [15]: lst = [1,2,3]
```

and your two attempts (note the correct indentation for the `return`):

```
In [18]: def solution1(lst): 
    ...:    arr = np.array(lst) 
    ...:    arr = lst.astype(np.float64) 
    ...:    return arr
    ...: def solution2(lst): 
    ...:    arr = np.array(lst) 
    ...:    arr = np.astype(np.float64) 
    ...:    return arr
    ...:
```

First try:

```
In [19]: solution1(lst)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

`astype` is a method of a `ndarray` (as the doc link in my comment shows).  `list` does not have such a method.  In python, each class has a defined set of `methods`.  Just because one class has such a method, it does not mean that another has the same.

For the second:

```
In [21]: solution2(lst)
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'astype'
    
In [22]: np.astype
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'astype'
```

Again you create an `arr`, but you try to use `astype` as `np` function.  You aren't specifying `arr` at all in that line.

Make an array from the list:

```
In [23]: np.array(lst)
Out[23]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

With this list the dtype is int:

```
In [24]: np.array(lst).dtype
Out[24]: dtype('int32')
```

The resulting array has a `astype` method:

```
In [25]: np.array(lst).astype(np.float64)
Out[25]: array([1., 2., 3.])
```

But `np.array` also accepts a `dtype` parameter:

```
In [26]: np.array(lst,dtype=np.float64)
Out[26]: array([1., 2., 3.])
```

If your list contains floats, you don't need any further conversion:

```
In [27]: np.array([1,2,.3])
Out[27]: array([1. , 2. , 0.3])

In [28]: np.array([1,2,.3]).dtype
Out[28]: dtype('float64')
```

In other words, you should simply have written:

```
def solution(lst):
    arr = np.array(lst)
    arr = arr.astype(np.float64)   # arr, not lst or np
    return arr
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to doing it the way you suggest with "you should simply have written..." instead of calling `np.array` with a `dtype` like `return np.array(lst, dtype=np.float64)`, or was that just for OP's ease of understanding?